# Simple inquiry about streaming data directly into Cloud SQL using Google DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

So I am working on a little project that sets up a streaming pipeline using Google Dataflow and apache beam. I went through some tutorials and was able to get a pipeline up and running streaming into BigQuery, but I am going to want to Stream it into a full relational DB(ie: Cloud SQL). I have searched through this site and throughout google and it seems that the best route to achieve that would be to use the JdbcIO. I am a bit confused here because when I am looking up info on how to do this it all refers to writing to cloud SQL in batches and not full out streaming.

My simple question is can I stream data directly into Cloud SQL or would I have to send it via batch instead.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `JdbcIO` - it does what you want, and it makes no assumption about whether its input `PCollection` is bounded or unbounded, so you can use it in any pipeline and with any Beam runner; the Dataflow Streaming Runner is no exception to that.

In case your question is prompted by reading its source code and seeing the word "batching": it simply means that for efficiency, it writes multiple records per database call - the overloaded use of the word "batch" can be confusing, but here it simply means that it tries to avoid the overhead of doing an expensive database call for every single record.

In practice, the number of records written per call is at most 1000 by default, but in general depends on how the particular runner chooses to execute this particular pipeline on this particular data at this particular moment, and can be less than that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the explanation! Makes total sense now.